# How do I write regex for an order ID link?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have the following link `https://events.mypage.com/orders/5r69dhhhsx/iz1ngvs53/`

While `https://events.mypage.eu/orders/` is always the same, `/5r69dy6hsx/iz1nap5s53/`will always differ, but with the same pattern of small letters and numbers. I need it for Google Analytics URL match. How can I write it?

My current version where I tried it looks like this:

`https://events.mypage.com/orders/([a-z][0-9])/([a-z][0-9])/`

Comment: I actually used this page here to try it https://regexr.com/ . I added my current version, but it seems to be wrong.

Comment: `([a-z][0-9])` will match exactly two characters, a letter and a digit. Try repeating them instead.

Comment: Replace `([a-z][0-9])` with `([a-z0-9]+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward slashes in the regex should be escaped. Using `([a-z][0-9])` will match only when there is a single smallcase character followed by a single digit number. To match multiple characters and numbers you can use `([a-z0-9]+)`. If you know the exact length or range of length of the `([a-z0-9]+)` part, you can use quantifiers such as `([a-z0-9]{exact length})` or `([a-z0-9]{lower limit, upper limit})` repectively.
Try this:
`https?:\/\/events\.mypage\.com\/orders\/([a-z0-9]+)\/([a-z0-9]+)\/`